# How to use a binding with an optional UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a parent view that has:

```swift
@State private var myImage:UIImage? = nil
```

I have a child view that wants to use it:

```swift
@Binding var myImage: UIImage?
```

Issue is it breaks my Coordinator call within that child view:

```swift
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(parent: self, myImage: $myImage)
    // error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<UIImage?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<UIImage>'"
}
```

When all the optionals are removed, there is no error with the makeCoordinator function in my child view. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @witekbobrowski Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<UIImage?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<UIImage>', updated in OP

Comment: do you declare a custom init for Coordinator? any chance you have the myImage parameter type set to `Binding<UIImage>`?

Comment: oh okay, I just noticed you said you are calling the makeCoordinator inside the childView. Could you provide some more context of the Coordinator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Error is thrown since your Coordinator apparently expects the myImage not to be `Binding<Optional<UIImage>>` but rather the `Binding<UIImage>`. The difference is significant, and the solution will depend on the desired design of your code.

#### 1. Get rid of Optionals

Remove the `?` to no longer deal with Optional, this will probably not suite your need but it's an option.

```swift
// in your parent
@State private var myImage: UIImage
// and child implementation
@Binding var myImage: UIImage
```

#### 2. Introduce Optionals to the Coordinator

Add the `?` to make the `Binding<UIImage>` a `Binding<Optional<UIImage>>`. Again, may not be best solution for your needs.

```swift
// in your Coordinator implementation
@Binding var myImage: UIImage?
```

#### 3. Provide new Binding with some default value

I would recommend the following:

```swift
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(parent: self, myImage: Binding(
        get { myImage ?? UIImage() }, // or some other default value
        set { myImage = $0 }
    ))
}
```

The solution really depends on what you are trying to achieve really. You need to decide if you actually want the Optional to be in the Coordinator or not.